# Morita equivalences and centers of some algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-rings, morita-equivalence

Let $k $ is an algebraically closed field of $\text{ch}(k)=0$.

Let $$E := k \langle x_0, x_1, x_2 ,x_3 \rangle/(x_ix_j-q_{ij}x_jx_i )_{0 \leq i,j \leq 3},$$ where $$(\text{deg}(x_0), \text{deg}(x_1), \text{deg}(x_2), \text{deg}(x_3)) = (1,1,2,2)$$ and
$$
(q_{ij}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1& 1 & \omega^2 \\
1 & 1& \omega^2 &1 \\
1 & \omega & 1 &1 \\
\omega & 1 &1 &1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
$\omega$ is a primitive 3-th root of unity.

We consider the localization $E' := E[x_0^{-1}]$ of $E$ by $x_0$.

Then, we have an equivalence $$\text{grmod}(E') \simeq \text{grmod}(\text{End}(E'\oplus E'(1)))$$ by graded Morita equivalence.
Here, we denote the category of finitely generated right graded $R$-modules by $\text{grmod}(R)$ for any noetherian graded algebra $R$.

Since $\operatorname{deg}(x_0)=1$, we have $E'$ and $\text{End}(E'\oplus E'(1))$ are strongly graded.
Moreover, we have $\operatorname{mod}(E'_{0}) \simeq \operatorname{mod}(E'')$, where $E''$ is
$$
E'' := \text{End}(E'\oplus E'(1))_0 \simeq 
\begin{pmatrix}
E'_{0} & E'_{1} \\
E'_{-1} & E'_{0}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
$E’_{i}$ is the degree $i$ part of $E’$.

On the other hand, since $\operatorname{mod}(E'_0) \simeq \operatorname{mod}(E'')$, we also have an isomorphism of the centers of algebras $Z(E'') \simeq Z(E'_{0})$.
(cf. [Theorem 4.4. in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01242.pdf). Here we use $E'_0, E''$ are finite over the centers.)

And, $$E'_0 \simeq k \langle X_1,X_2,X_3 \rangle /(X_iX_j-Q_{ij}X_jX_i),$$ where $$X_1 = x_1x_0^{-1},X_2=x_2x_0^{-2},X_3=x_3x_0^{-2}$$ and
$$
(Q_{ij})=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& \omega^2 & \omega \\
\omega& 1 &\omega^2 \\
\omega^2 & \omega &1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So, we have $Z(E'_0)$ is generated by $X_1^3,X_2^3,X_3^3,X_1X_2X_3$.
Although $Z(E'') \subset Z(E'_0) \subset E’_0$, $Z(E'') \not\simeq Z(E'_0)$.
This is because $X_1X_2X_3$ is not in $Z(E'')$.
In detail,
$$
(X_1X_2X_3) 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\neq 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
(X_1X_2X_3)
$$
in $E''$.
Here, we identify
$$
X_1X_2X_3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1X_2X_3 & 0 \\
0 & X_1X_2X_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By this identification, we think of $X_1X_2X_3$ as an element of $E''$.

However, this contradicts $Z(E'') \simeq Z(E'_{0})$.

**Question**
Where do we have a mistake in the above discussion?

Any comments welcome.
Thank you.

**Edit(9/10)** : (What I wrote here was not correct. So, I will modify for now. The conclusion may not change ...)

First, note that all graded modules which appear are *right* graded modules from the above definition.
(You can find it below the definition of $E'$.)

$\begin{pmatrix}
 X_1X_2X_3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$
represents the homomorphism $  E'(1) \rightarrow E'(1)$ which maps $e$ to $(X_1X_2X_3)e$ (left multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$.) .

$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  X_1X_2X_3 
\end{pmatrix}$
represents the homomorphism $  E' \rightarrow E'$ which maps $e$ to $(X_1X_2X_3)e$ (left multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$ ).

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x_0 \\ 
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$
represents the homomorphism $E' \rightarrow E'(1)$ which maps $e$ to $x_0 e$ (left multiplication by $x_0$).

These 3 maps are homomorphisms of right graded modules.

Comment: I'm not sure, but your endomorphism $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & x_0 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is probably *right* multiplication by this element, and so it commutes with *left* multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$. Could this be the explanation?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.
You mean that $
(X_1X_2X_3) 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
(X_1X_2X_3)
$
in $E''$ ?

Comment: I am so sorry.
I am confused and still don't understand.

Comment: Read my edited answer, and then play with the matrices.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience.
Is what I wrote in Edit wrong?

Comment: Here's another way of putting it. Although left multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$ is an endomorphism of $E'(1)$, it's not the endomorphism you need. What you need is the endomorphism $X_1X_2X_3$ of $E'$, conjugated by the isomorphism between $E'$ and $E'(1)$ given by multiplication by $x_0$.

Comment: Perhaps, have I misunderstood how $E_0'$ is embedded in $E''$ ?

Comment: I think that may be the source of your confusion about left and right multiplications.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out in your own mind? Did you want accept my answer, or are you still confused?

Comment: I think I understand now. The reason why I misunderstood is that I thought $X_1X_2X_3$  as an element in $E''$ is given by a  $\textit{left}$ multiplication of $X_1X_2X_3$ in $E''$. In order for $X_1X_2X_3$ to be a center in $E''$, I should have thought $X_1X_2X_3$  as an element in $E''$ is given by a $\textit{right} $ multiplication of $X_1X_2X_3$ in $E''$.
This is what you wanted to tell me, isn't it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that in your matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&x_0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, the $x_0$ denotes the isomorphism of modules given by *left* multiplication by $x_0$, so it commutes with *right* multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$ in $E''$, which is the same as left multiplication by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} X_1X_2X_3&0\\0&x_0^{-1}X_1X_2X_3x_0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. So this is your central element of the endomorphism ring, and *not* left multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$.

**Edited** to make the answer for right modules rather than left modules.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand, but the matrices
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
x_0^{-1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
also commute with multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$ in $E''$ ?
I need to verify that to show $X_1X_2X_3$ is a central element.

Comment: Your matrices representing endomorphisms are presumably all right multiplications, because otherwise they're not homomorphisms of modules with respect to left multiplication. Associativity says that right multiplications commute with left multiplications: $(xa)y=x(ay)$.

Comment: In the question,
I identify 
$X_1X_2X_3 =
(\begin{smallmatrix}
X_1X_2X_3 & 0 \\
0 & X_1X_2X_3 \\
\end{smallmatrix}).
$

So, $(X_1X_2X_3) (\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix})$ and $
(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix})
(X_1X_2X_3)
$ mean 
$(\begin{smallmatrix}
X_1X_2X_3 & 0 \\
0 & X_1X_2X_3 \\
\end{smallmatrix})
(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} )$ and  
$ (\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & x_0 \\
0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} )
(\begin{smallmatrix}
X_1X_2X_3 & 0 \\
0 & X_1X_2X_3 \\
\end{smallmatrix} )$ respectively.

Comment: From the comments above I think multiplication from either side would make sense.
Is that not the case?

Comment: No, that is not the case. Left multiplication by $x_0$ is not a homomorphism of left modules, so you have to use right multiplication. And left multiplication by a central element is what you need for $X_1X_2X_3$. You can't just choose.

Comment: Sorry for the repeated trouble, I wanted to ask you about what I wrote in Edit.
In this case, I also had the same misunderstanding again ?

Comment: Yes, you still have the same misunderstanding. The point is that for a ring $A$, the endomorphisms of $A$ as a left module are isomorphic to $A^{\mathop{\rm op}}$. You insist on confusing $A$ with $A^{\mathop{\rm op}}$, with the obvious consequence that things don't multiply the way you think they do. This is the last time I'm going to say this.

Comment: I will add one further comment, then I'm done. Left multiplication by $X_1X_2X_3$ is the endomorphism that commutes with right multiplication by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&x_0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. It is equivalent to right multiplication by the diagonal matrix with entries $X_1X_2X_3$ and $\omega X_1X_2X_3$ (or is it $\omega^2$? I can't be bothered to check). Whichever it is, these endomorphisms commute.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain this better.